Expected number of solutions of a random quadratic polynomial system over a finite field
Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a field of $q$ elements. Let $a_{i,j,k}$, $b_{i,j}$, $c_i$ ($1 \leq i \leq m$, $1 \leq j \leq k \leq n$) be independent uniformly distributed random variables in $\mathbb{F}_q$, and let $N$ be the number of solutions $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{F}_q^n$ of the quadratic polynomial systems of $m$ equations in $n$ unknowns
$$\sum_{1 \leq j \leq k \leq n} a_{i,j,k} x_j x_k + \sum_{1 \leq h \leq n} b_{i,h} x_h + c_i = 0 \quad\text{ for } i = 1, \dots, m .$$
Is the expected value $\mathbf{E}[N]$ of $N$ known?
It seems to me that the question is sufficiently natural to have been probably studied before. I guess that $\mathbf{E}[N]$ could be computed using techniques such as exponential sums, but I'm not an expert about them.
By searching on the web, I keep finding vague claims such has: "if  $m = n$ then the random system is expected to have exactly one solution," and I was not able to find any precise (and proved!) result.
Thank for any suggestion or reference.

I don't know any formal results, but maybe results about average case hardness of SAT (or maybe another NP-complete problem is more appropriate) are relevant.

Actually, I might be missing something, but isn't this just $q^{n-m}$? You can use linearity of expectation, and the probability of a random system being fulfilled by a given vector is $q^{-m}$

@PeterMueller Yes, you are right, it is quite easy indeed :-) You can turn the comment into an answer

@en-drix ... and if you are happy with the answer, you might accept it :-)

@PeterMueller I accepted it, sorry for the delay... I was probably convinced of having already accepted the answer and I forgot about it :-/

The expected number of $N$ is $q^{n-m}$. One can either argue as in the comments by Command Master, or perform a simple double counting argument: Let $S$ be the set of polynomial systems with the given parameters, $X$ be the elements from $\mathbb F_q^n$, and $M$ be the set of pairs $(s,x)\in S\times X$ such that $x$ is a solution of $s$.
With $N(s)$ the number of solutions of the system $s$, we thus have
\begin{equation}
\lvert M\rvert=\sum_{s\in S}N(s).
\end{equation}
On the other hand, given $x\in X$, the number of $s\in S$ such that $x$ is a solution of $s$ is $\frac{\lvert S\rvert}{q^m}$, as the $a_{i,j,k}$'s and $b_{i,h}$'s can be arbitrarily chosen and the $c_i$'s then are unique.
Hence
\begin{equation}
\lvert M\rvert=\sum_{x\in X}\frac{\lvert S\rvert}{q^m}=q^n\frac{\lvert S\rvert}{q^m}
\end{equation}
and therefore
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\lvert S\rvert}\sum_{s\in S}N(s)=q^{n-m}.
\end{equation}
